# Flask/SQLAlchemy Insert Into Database

Tags: python, ajax, json, sqlalchemy, flask

Using Flask and SQLAlchemy on my localhost, I am looking to be able to submit a simple contact form and, using AJAX, pass the submitted data along to my Flask API and then insert it into my local database, named `contact.db`.

To set up my database, I put together a script named `setup.py`, which successfully creates a database in my working directory. Its contents look as follows:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy import Column, Date, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, backref

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///contact.db', echo=True)
Base = declarative_base()

########################################################################
class Contact(Base):
    """"""
    __tablename__ = "contact"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    f_name = Column(String)
    l_name = Column(String)
    email = Column(String)
    message = Column(String)

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, f_name, l_name, email, message):
        """"""
        self.f_name = f_name
        self.l_name = l_name
        self.email = email
        self.message = message

# create tables
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

My simple contact page collects the data and submits it to my flask route `/contact/request` using AJAX (I have confirmed this to work via the console). For reference, however, here is the code I use in `contact.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Contact</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>




<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#submitForm").click(function()
      {
        var firstName = $("#f_name").val();
        var lastName = $("#l_name").val();
        var email = $("#email").val();
        var mess = $("#mess").val();

        var nud = {
          "f_name" : firstName,
          "l_name" : lastName,
          "email" : email,
          "message" : mess
        }


        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "/contact/request",
          data: JSON.stringify(nud, null, '\t'),
          contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
          success: function(result) {
            console.log(result);
          }
        })
      });
  })
</script>



</head>
<body>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3"></div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h1 style="text-align: center">Contact Me</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <form role="form">
          <div class="form-horizontal" class="form-group" style="width:50%">
            <label for="name has-success">First Name</label>
            <input class="form-control input-md" type="text" class="form-control" id="f_name" placeholder="Matthew">
          </div><br />
          <div class="form-horizontal" class="form-group" style="width:50%">
            <label for="email">Last Name</label>
            <input class="form-control input-md" type="text" class="form-control" id="l_name" placeholder="Gross">
          </div><br />
           <div class="form-horizontal" class="form-group" style="width:50%">
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input class="form-control input-md" type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="mattkgross@gmail.com">
          </div><br />
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="aboutMe">Message</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" id="mess" placeholder="What's up?" rows="3" ></textarea>
          </div>
          <div>
           <button type="button" input type "submit" class="btn btn-success" id="submitForm">Submit</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Finally, I have my actual Flask API script that I run in order to start up my service on localhost. The `/contact` route works fine. However, when I send the data via my form submission, I get an internal server error. This is undoubtedly being caused by my incorrect attempt at inserting the parsed JSON into my contact database. Below is the code used in my `api.py`:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
from flask import render_template

import datetime
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from setup import Contact

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/contact')
def contact():
    return render_template('contact.html')

@app.route('/contact/request', methods=["POST"])
def contact_request():
    if request.method == "POST":
        engine = create_engine('sqlite:///contact.db', echo=True)

        # Create a Session
        Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
        session = Session()

        new_contact = Contact(request.json['f_name'],
                              request.json['l_name'],
                              request.json['email'],
                              request.json['message'])

        # Add the record to the session object
        session.add(new_contact)
        # commit the record the database
        session.commit()

        #return str(request.json)

app.debug = True
app.run()
```

If I comment out the two lines:

```
session.add(new_contact)
session.commit()
```

and replace them with `return str(request.json)`, my console successfully returns the JSON I sent. I am just completely lost as to where I am going wrong in inserting my data into the database and why it is throwing an error at me for my attempt.

Any help you can give me would be very much appreciated - hopefully it's something simple I overlooked in being new to this whole thing. Thanks!

Comment: What's the error? Also you have to return something or it won't work. Have you tried inserting and returning a value?

Comment: Unbelievable. The sole problem was that I was not returning anything... I feel very dumb right now. Thank you! If you wouldn't mind writing your solution up as an answer, I will go ahead and accept it. Thanks! :)

Comment: thanks. Added it as answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In flask you have to return something for your route otherwise it will lead to odd behavior. In your case you could return something as simple as an "OK" to let your AJAX know the function completed successfully.